# Ajax não funciona

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho este código abaixo em ajax:

```
    <script>
$("a").live("click", function(event) {      
      var targeturl = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
               type: "get",
               url: "/"+targeturl +"",
               data: "",
               dataType: "html",
               success: function(html){
                   jQuery('#add2').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
                   location.reload();
               }

           });  // closing for  ajax
        event.preventDefault(); 

  });
</script>
```

E este código em PHP:

```
while($row = $stm->fetch())  {

  $color = completePayment($row["pago"]);

      "<div id=add9 align=middle style='color: {$color}; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 1px darkblue'>" .$row['pago'] . " <div id=add2 align=middle <br><br> <a id=add2 href=pago.php?id=". $row['id'] ."><img src=images/pago.png><a href=naopago.php?id=". $row['id'] . " ><img src=images/naopago4.png >
```

Apenas aloquei o trecho que interessa do código. Na pagina tem duas imagens (Pago e Não Pago), quando clico em pago, ele pega o ID do usuário e dá um Update no banco , setando o valor SIM, e automaticamente este mesmo valor na pagina, quando não está pago, faz o mesmo processo. Trás a informação NÂO setando este valor no Banco. O problema que o Ajax não está funcionando, quando tiro o Ajax a pagina executa e quando deixo este código, ela não executa, clico nas imagens e nada acontece.

Comment: Qual a versão do jQuery?

Comment: tenho dois setados jquery-1.8.2.js e 1.9.0

Comment: Deixei apenas o 1.9.0 e agora ele executa, porem dando submit ao arquivo que faz a alteração no banco, e o certo era permanecer na pagina sem dar submit a outra né.

Comment: Não pode ter 2 jQuery. Use somente um. Sobre o que disse acima você quer que a pagina não de refresh ne?

Comment: Exato, com dois nada acontecia, agora com a ultima versão, ele direciona para a pagina que faz o update no banco e o certo era fazer o update do banco sem sair da pagina.

Comment: Retire isso do script: ` location.reload();`. Ai ta pedindo pra recarregar a pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Deixe apenas uma biblioteca JQuery carregada.

E o seu script Javascript deve ficar assim:

```
<script>
$("a").live("click", function(event) {      
  var targeturl = $(this).attr("link");

  $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: "/"+targeturl +"",
           data: "",
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(html){
               jQuery('#add2').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
           }

       });  // closing for  ajax
    event.preventDefault(); 

 });
</script>
```

No php altere está parte assim:

```
 while($row = $stm->fetch())  {

 $color = completePayment($row["pago"]);

  "<div id=add9 align=middle style='color: {$color}; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 1px darkblue'>" .$row['pago'] . " <div id=add2 align=middle <br><br> <button id=add2 link=pago.php?id=". $row['id'] ."><img src=images/pago.png><button link=naopago.php?id=". $row['id'] . " ><img src=images/naopago4.png >
```

Comment: Fiz o teste retirando esta linha: location.reload();, porem acontece a mesma coisa. Ao clicar na imagem que contem como href o arquivo php que dá o update no banco, direciona para uma pagina em branco, setando os valores. Porem é necessário permanecer na tela anterior sem direcionar.

Comment: @user54154 Editei a resposta.

Comment: @user54154 Você não pode ter `href` em um botão que não quer seja feito refresh na pagina.

Comment: @user54154 Alterei o `href` para outro atributo.

Comment: Fiz as alterações para LINK no lugar do href, as imagens perderam o LINK e nada acontece ao clicar nelas.

Comment: Modifique a tag a para button. Veja que deve ter o atributo link dentro da tag. E no JavaScript também deve ter esse atributo na segunda linha.

Comment: @user54154 Não conseguiu?

Comment: Olá Willian, consegui sim, não da forma esperada, precisarei estudar mais meu codigo e entender o motivo real do problema. Eu voltei com o Href, dando um location no arquivo redirecionado (pago ou naopago.php) para voltar a pagina atual. Assim que eu corrigir, informo aqui com a solução. Foi apenas uma solução paliativa.

Comment: Amigo, redirecionamentos internos não e o correto. E para dar certo como te passei por ultimo. Em praticamente em todos meus projetos uso desta maneira.

Comment: Você deve estar fazendo algo errado.

Comment: Irei avaliar com calma suas orientações, entendo que é errado sim, foi só paliativo. Assim que eu terminar te dou um feedback neste.Agradeço